# Autoscaling axis after pan or zoom in Visiblox chart

Tags: c#, visiblox

I have a Visiblox line chart that allows zooming and panning on the XAxis (but not the YAxis). After zooming or panning to a particular region of the chart, I would like to have the YAxis range and ticks recalculated based on the visible data only. I tried setting AutoScaleToVisibleData="True" on the YAxis, but this does not work as zooming and panning do not set XAxis.Range, and XAxis.Range must change in order for the YAxis's AutoScaleToVisibleData property to have an effect.

**EDIT**

I am now attempting to use the IAxis.AdoptZoomAsRange() function but can't seem to figure it out. Relevant example code below:

XAML:

```
<charts:Chart Name="chart">
    <charts:Chart.Behaviour>
        <charts:BehaviourManager AllowMultipleEnabled="True">
            <charts:PanBehaviour IsEnabled="True" YPanEnabled="False" PanEnded="PanBehaviour_PanEnded" />
            <charts:ZoomBehaviour IsEnabled="True" YZoomEnabled="False" AnimationEnabled="False" ZoomMode="MouseWheel" ZoomEnded="ZoomBehaviour_ZoomEnded" />
        </charts:BehaviourManager>
    </charts:Chart.Behaviour>
    <charts:Chart.XAxis>
        <charts:DateTimeAxis />
    </charts:Chart.XAxis>
    <charts:Chart.YAxis>
        <charts:LinearAxis AutoScaleToVisibleData="True" />
    </charts:Chart.YAxis>
</charts:Chart>
```

Code-behind:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    DataSeries<DateTime, double> dataSeries = new DataSeries<DateTime, double>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        dataSeries.Add(new DataPoint<DateTime, double>(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(i), i));

    LineSeries lineSeries = new LineSeries();
    lineSeries.DataSeries = dataSeries;
    chart.Series.Add(lineSeries);
}

private void PanBehaviour_PanEnded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    chart.YAxis.AdoptZoomAsRange();
}

private void ZoomBehaviour_ZoomEnded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    chart.YAxis.AdoptZoomAsRange();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The AdoptZoomAsRange method on IAxis is probably what you're looking for - there's a downloadable example it being used in this [blog post](http://www.visiblox.com/blog/2011/05/plotting-candlestick-series-with-visiblox-charts#rescaling) which should hopefully make that clearer.

[disclosure: I work on Visiblox]

Comment: This looks like what I can't figure out how to get it to work. I've edited my original post to show an example. I try to execute the method after any zoom or pan and AutoScaleToVisibleData is set to True on the YAxis, but nothing happens to the YAxis after I pan or zoom.

Comment: You need to AdoptZoomAsRange on the XAxis not the YAxis.  The AutoScaleToVisibleData on the YAxis means it will calculate it's range based on what is visible on the XAxis' range, so you need to reset that range every time.

[disclaimer: I work for Visiblox]

Comment: Applying AdoptZoomAsRange to the XAxis instead worked; however, now the chart will not zoom out using the mouse wheel. AdoptZoomAsRange is called in both PanBehavior_PanEnded and ZoomBehavior_ZoomEnded. If I remove it in ZoomBehavior_ZoomEnded then I can zoom out, but only partially if the chart has already been zoomed in quite far.